# why would we convert univariate to bivariate normal distribution

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have two variables like this:

```
x   y
10  20
5   18
20  30
```

etc

can somebody explain to me why would we convert this to bivariate normal distribution? I looked at multiple docs explaining, non of them so far explain why would we convert it to bi or multivariate normal distribution.

I would really appreciate if anyone can explain this to me in lamest terms.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why use a bivariate distribution is because $x$ and $y$ use different Normal distribution. However these two might have a covariance between them...

We say that a bivariate distribution has a vector mean $\begin{pmatrix} \mu_x \\ \mu_y\end{pmatrix}$, the means of $x$ and $y$ respectively and covariance matrix : $$\Sigma = \begin{pmatrix}\sigma_x^2 & \sigma_{xy}^2\\\sigma_{yx}^2 &\sigma_y^2 \end{pmatrix}$$ where $\sigma_{xy}^2 = \sigma_{yx}^2$ is the covariance between both random variables. If this is positive, then they will have the same "variations" and if it is negative, they will have opposite variations.

Of course, $\sigma_x^2$ and $\sigma_y^2$ are the respective variances of $x$ and $y$.

If $\sigma_{xy}^2 = 0$, then this means that there is no covariance between them and you can write the bivariate normal distribution as two one-variable distributions.

Comment: thank you for the answer. However, I have some more questions. The reason I am asking you all this is that there is an application for this model that I would like to understand how this works. For example, given x and y, I like to predict x given a y value with a simulation. After forming this covariance matrix and bivariate distribution, given y how am I picking x values with random simulation. Can you explain that to me please?

Comment: There will be no exact values, just probabilities. Have a look at conditional distributions. Using this you can find a density function which will give you the likelihood that $x$ takes a certain value.

Comment: I meant to say estimating the mean of x (not exact values)

Comment: Are you saying you have the values of $x$ after the simulation?

Comment: no, given a mean value for y, I need to estimate the x (mean) values with simulation.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you say that you have the bivariate distribution of $x$ and $y$? Or just the covariance matrix?

Comment: I have a bivariate normal distribution of x and y and given this distribution, I need to estimate the mean of x, given a mean of y with simulation. I don't understand where would I draw the mean of x values from given the bivariate normal distribution. I am missing something but I don't know what.

Comment: The bivariate distribution has two components, the mean vector and the covariance matrix. The mean vector has two elements, one is the mean for $x$ and the other one the mean for $y$. If you say $x$ given $y$, you need to use conditional probabilities.